# Navigating up in activities Android mechanism

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i have 2 activities MainActivity and GalleryActivity, so:
MainActivity -> GalleryActivity

in my main Activity i have GoogleMap fragment, from gallery i can choose picture with geotag, when I click back arrow on ActionBar i want to set up a marker on a map with position from picture tag.

I'm calling gallery from main:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,GalleryActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

and I'm getting back to main:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

Am I calling `onCreate()` of MainActivity when I'm doing this? All changes that i made before calling child are gone (map markers, map position), i want them to stay as they were unless user pick up another picture.
How can I do that in simple way?

I'm using map object from google api in a fragment

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
```

and XML:

```
<fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Should I use `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` that can save important data that i want to store before calling a child Activity? how I can pass new geoTag or whole image between child and Main in Child to Main order?

Comment: what does NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask do?

Comment: It is closing activity that is calling it and it shows(open) parent activity, in my case MainActivity, info from:
[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpFromSameTask%28android.app.Activity%29)